# Intelllij Idea Not able to detect My iOS Device

Tags: ios, flutter, intellij-idea

I created a flutter app and it is not detecting my iPad.

[image]

In the image, you can see it is showing `<no devices>`.
My iPad uses `iOS 12.4.8`.
But when I connect it to my android 10 phone it can detect it.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mac to be able to debug or run your app on an iphone or ipad.